# Microsoft Ribbon window threw an exception

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am getting an error for the Ribbon controls library, when this errors it breaks at the new() method in the class that is using the ribbon controls.

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in WpfPluggableApp.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonWindow' threw an exception.

But when I continue I get this error instead

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfPluggableApp.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '5'.

There is nothing I can see which is going to effect it at line 3 of the MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <DockPanel>
        <Menu Name="mnu" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

        </Menu>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModels}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=isSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel MinWidth="120">
                                    <Button 
                                    Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                                    Content="X"
                                    Cursor="Hand"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    Focusable="False"
                                    FontFamily="Courier" 
                                    FontSize="9"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"  
                                    Margin="0,1,0,0"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    Width="16" Height="16"    
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    />
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="10" 
                                    Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    />
                                </DockPanel>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />


                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
```

Here is the xaml for the ribbon:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="MainRibbonWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    Title="MainRibbonWindow"
    x:Name="MainRibbonWindow"
    WindowState="Maximized" MinHeight="480" MinWidth="640">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">

    </ribbon:Ribbon>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModels}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=isSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel MinWidth="120">
                                <Button 
                                    Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                                    Content="X"
                                    Cursor="Hand"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    Focusable="False"
                                    FontFamily="Courier" 
                                    FontSize="9"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"  
                                    Margin="0,1,0,0"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    Width="16" Height="16"    
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                />
                                <ContentPresenter 
                                        Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 />
                            </DockPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <!--<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />-->

            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

It might be a case of needing a fresh pair of eyes to look at it! If you can see the problem let me know.

Thanks,
Sam

-----------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------

Issue has been resolved, I was referencing the wrong class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have sorted it. Had the wrong version of a class library which was making it error.